# How to create a startup prompt that populates definition queries on multiple feature classes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, vba, definition-query

I would like to create an ArcGIS start up prompt or custom button that asks for a user's initials and then populates multiple feature class & layer definition queries.

More specifically, I would like to standardize my departments layer organization for new employees and would like to customize the definition queries & symbology of several layers in each employee's MXD.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  If 10.1 or later are you happy to consider writing a Python-addin?

Comment: I'm currently using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 for Desktop (Build (3143) - another method I'd consider would be to create a button that users would click and get a prompt for their initials, then that gets populated to the various layers' Def Query... Whichever is most efficient and makes most sense.